# How to search for classes/interfaces by method name in the Java API?

Tags: search, java

I'm reading **Java Manual**. There is an example in [**the List Interface** section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html):

```
a[i] = a[j].times(a[k]);
```

I'd like to know whose the `times` method is. How can I find all this method's classes? Google can't help here. I print:

```
java 7 api times
```

but Google just cuts off `s` from `times` and gives me results for **the Time Class** and **the Date Class** which has no `times` method.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is just an example of a method call on an array object.

```
a[i] = a[j].times(a[k]);
```

In this case `times` would be a method from the element stored in `a[i]`. `times` is not a method of  standard Java collections.

I think the naming of `times` is a bit bad in this example because it can make you think there is a method that does something X times (like the [times method in groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#times%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)).

Comment: and also, an example of the sort of problem web searches (like google) are not good at solving:  when you're looking for something that doesn't exist, google will throw cr&p at you instead of admitting it couldn't find what you asked for.

Comment: It is a kind of pseudo code, a bit unlucky, .times implicates multiple invocation or sth. to me..

Answer (score 1):

They probably assume that there is

```
class Number {
    int value;

    Number(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    Number times(Number n) {
        return new Number(value * n.value);
    }
}
```

and there is an array of Numbers

```
Number[] a
```

then it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid automatic stemming of your query terms, as described in [Google's "Interpreting Your Query" Guide](http://www.googleguide.com/interpreting_queries.html):

> If you only want to search for pages that contain some term(s)
>   exactly, surround each such word or phrase with quotation marks (" ").
>   See Quoted Phrases and Quotation Marks Replace the + Operator.
>
> Google doesn't match variants when your query consists of a single
>   term.

So a query that does better than the one you posted is:

```
"times" site:docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api
```

I still can't get Google to use the paren, though. :-( Without that there doesn't seem to be a way to exclude all the occurrences of the word in documentation (which there are a ton of). If there was a return type that might help a lot.